# returned value from realloc() give a segmentation fault

Tags: c, memory-management, gcc, cygwin

```
#define BUF_SIZE 10

char *html = "foo:baa\r\nxxx:yyyy:\r\nLocation:........................................\r\Connection:close\r\n\r\n";
char *p = (char*)html, *buf, *pbuf, *tbuf;
int buf_size = BUF_SIZE, hsize = 0;

 if((buf = malloc(buf_size)) == NULL) FAILED("NO MEMORY!\n");
   pbuf = buf;

    while(*p != '\0' && *(p + 1) != '\r' && *(p + 2) != '\n') {
                    if((hsize + 1) >= buf_size) {
                        printf("Do realloc!\n");
                        buf_size += BUF_SIZE + 2; 
                        tbuf = realloc(buf, buf_size); // BUF_SIZE 
                        if(tbuf != NULL) {
                            buf = tbuf;
                        } else {
                            printf(" NO MEMORY!\n");
                            exit(1);
                        }
                    }

                    *pbuf ++= *p++, hsize ++;
            }
```

But it give an

```
Do realloc!
Do realloc!
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0022A814  7798EFA3  (000000FC, 0000EA60, 00000000, 0022A948)
0022A828  7798EF52  (000000FC, 0000EA60, 000000A4, 0022A924)
0022A948  610DB059  (00000000, 00000001, 0022A978, 0000000C)
0022AA38  610D841E  (00000000, 61102908, 003B0023, 00230000)
0022AA98  610D88EE  (20038878, 0000000C, 0022AAC8, 00000006)
0022AB48  610D8A40  (00000E3C, 00000006, 00000001, 20010340)
0022AB68  610D8A6C  (00000006, 0022CE80, 0022ABD4, 20038883)
0022AB98  610D8CF5  (004031AA, 20010340, 0022ABE8, 61138596)
20010348  6110F935  (73756A2E, DF0DF02E, 200000C8, 00000000)
```

I have no idea how to fix this! Actually, I am not sure that it's a really segmentation fault.

Comment: Where does the variable html come from?

Comment: Yes, please tell us the contents and type of `html`.

Comment: @Jack: That's not helpful.  Surely you know its underlying type and can post its contents here.

Comment: @EdS.: Added an more real example. I'm trying to get only some value from HTTP headers.

Comment: @Jack I posted an answer that enumerates the issues in your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two fatal issues:

1. `pbuf` is assigned the value of `buf` at init but then is never updated. `realloc` is not guaranted to return the same address after `malloc` (and the subsequent `realloc` calls).
2. You are overflowing `pbuf` here before calling the required `realloc`:

   `*pbuf ++= *p++, hsize ++;`

Comment: Thanks so much! I would +10, if I could!

Comment: Another question: I'm losing the older values after subsequent `realloc()` calls,as have you mentioned in second point. How to fix this?

Comment: @Jack: If you have another question, [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)! The comments aren't really the place for that.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the #define version of BUF_SIZE.

```
realloc(buf, BUF_SIZE);
```

You should use the computed value that is stored in buf_size.

```
realloc(buf, buf_size);
```

Comment: This still does not explain the segfault.

Comment: @ouah: `pBuf` is never initialized, yet is *is* dereferenced.  That explains the seg fault.

Comment: @EdS. he should put this in the answer

Answer (score 3):

```
*pbuf ++= *p++, hsize ++;
```

You never initialize `pBuf`.  Also:

```
tbuf = realloc(buf, BUF_SIZE);
```

Should be:

```
tbuf = realloc(buf, buf_size);
```

EDIT:

As @ouah noted in the comments, and considering that you do in fact initialize `pBuf` (though we can't see it), it seems that the way in which you manipulate `p` is the likely culprit.  What is the type and contents of `html`?  Is it null terminated?  Are any of your `*(p + n)` expressions overruning it's valid bounds?

Comment: @trumpetlicks: Yeah I saw that, but since I have no idea as it isn't shown to us, I am assuming everything done to that pointer is valid.

Comment: Kinda figured, but I thought since your answer spoke about never initializing I would simply comment under yours rather than try to leave another answer :-)

Comment: @Jack in that case look that `html` is null terminated and `strlen((char *) html)` is `>=  2`.

Comment: @ouah - Thats what I was getting at!!!  He is essentially moving through p, but p is initialized with (char*)html!!!

Comment: @ouah: I think you should post that as an answer because, considering the feedback on `pBuf`, it seems to be the likely culprit.

Comment: @EdS. there are too many answers, I let you add this to yours if you want.

Comment: @Jack: So which line throws the error exactly?  And what do you mean when you say that your not sure if it is actually a segfault? The error is not really open to interpretation, which is it?

Comment: @Jack: Also: *"while(*foo); Don't get a infinite-loop."* - That hardly proves that `html` is valid.  All it proves is that a 0 byte is encountered somewhere. If you're overrunning its bounds anything can happen, i.e., undefined behavior.

Comment: @EdS.: I said it because I don't have sure that it's a segmentation fault. I get this error message as you can seen in my question.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked at your code exhaustively, but do you really mean to be calling `realloc()` with `BUF_SIZE` (which is a fixed preprocessor constant), rather than `buf_size`? It's generally not good practice to have symbols with different values and purposes which differ only by case (partially because of these sorts of errors).

Comment: You are right. Thanks so much! I have fixed it, but I get yet same error.

Comment: @Jack, as others have pointed out, the segfault is likely because you haven't initialized `pBuf`.

Comment: I did it in my real code. But when I edited here, I forgot to retype it.

Answer (score 1):

You are re-calculating `buf_size`, but you are not using it in `realloc`. I think it should be

```
tbuf = realloc(buf, buf_size); // not BUF_SIZE
```

Currently, you keep re-allocating at size 10.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the many bugs mentioned in the many other answers: After you call `realloc`, `pbuf` is no longer valid, yet you dereference it.

Comment: I tried: `tbuf = realloc(buf, buf_size); if(tbuf != NULL) { buf = tbuf; pbuf = buf;` But looks like I'm overflowing the older values, getting only the last 8 characters. Can you give an simple code example how to do this?

Comment: You need something like: `pbuf = tbuf + (pbuf - buf);`